# primefaces calendar tag cannot popup and no effect

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use primefaces calendar tag to write a very short practice
but cannot work and cannot popup.
primefaces jar is 3.5 version.

xhtml page

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile" 
    contentType="text/html">    

    <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date1}" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd"/>

</f:view>
```

Bean

```
private Date date1 = new Date();//can show today
private Date date1 ;//show nothing
```

faces-config.xml

```
 <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>calendarBean</managed-bean-name>
     <managed-bean-class>
         com.WWUMOBPRIM.calendarBean
     </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
```

thanks,I change my code to `@ManagedBean` and `@SessionScoped`,

consol in chrome show "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined"
from primefaces-mobile.js.xhtml

Comment: do you have any error in your log? why don't you use annotations for the ManagedBean? Just annotate the bean with `@ManagedBean` and `@SessionScoped` for example

Comment: I found the answer from primefaces.org,see this url. http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=29876#p97390

Comment: it would be nice if you write an answer to your own topic with the changes you made to fix your issue. you can accept it after 3 days. so other will see that there is a solution to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the anwser from primefaces forum,
we should add `<html>` tag and using `</h:head>` `<h:body>` tag to enclose our web page,
the template page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">

    <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>PrimeFaces Test</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>    

                     <p:calendar />
                 Put other here                                 
            </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

the page runs well ,but still have little bug in mobile version,
if `<p:calendar />` enclose by `<pm>` tag,
the style little difference to web version.